# Offline C IDE with custom inputs

Tags: windows, ide, c

Can someone suggest me an offline IDE of C language for Windows (not Visual Studio, it is too heavy)?

It should have a feature of taking custom inputs or Stdin Inputs just like the one present online like codechef, jdoodle etc.

I am looking for a non-interactive IDE unlike code blocks and Dev-C++ which are interactive.

Comment: I have been coding C for \*cough\* decades now, and I don't understand your question (but I did upvote it). If you can explain a little more, I will try my best to help (best C IDEs, in no particular order are [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/), both free, and [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) (not free).  There are more, of course, and I mean no offense to others)

Comment: For e.g.-Suppose you are writing a C code on Code Blocks and it requires a number as an input. Then after building and executing it, you gave an input and got a result which was wrong. You modified your code and then again built and executed it. You need to give the input again and you have to do this everytime you execute your code. But if you were using say CodeChef then it doesn't matter how many times you modify your code, you need to give the input only ones and that also before executing the code (i.e. not during runtime). I am looking for the second type of an offline IDE.

Comment: That makes it clearer. Thanks (+1). If it is only one input, such that you could run `myprogram.exe some_text`, then you can do that in any of the IDEs specified. In fact, even if you need to  read repeated inputs, you can do that in Eclipse. I know that I have

Comment: Visual Studio has the required feature (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043986/debugging-with-visual-studio-using-redirected-standard-input)). And Visual Studio is actually rather light-weight, at least it is considerably lighter than chrome or eclipse.

Comment: @user7860670 Visual Studio was already excluded.